# How to POST Json in HttpContent and Parse it in API Controller?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api2, httpcontent

I am wanting to take JSON, put it in a StringContent and pass it to my API. From there, i am wanting to deserialize the JSON back over to a class and use it from there. Currently i am getting an error for trying to deserialize which from what i can tell, the logInfo is empty when reaching the API. When i try writing out the parameter, it's empty in the event log. See the Consumer and API Code below.

```
        public void Log(LogInfo logInfo)
        {
        using (var client = CreateHttpClient())
        {
            var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logInfo);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("Logger/Log", content).Result;

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{response} was not successful.");
            }
        }
    }


        [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Log([FromBody] string logInfo)
    {
        //var logData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogInfo>(logInfo);
        EventLog.WriteEntry("TestApp", logInfo);
        EventLog.WriteEntry("TestApp", Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        //Log(logData);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why this was assigned a -1 when it wasn't an answer? lol If you don't understand the question then ask...sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller method Log should take LogInfo parameter. This LogInfo model is a class that acts as DTO/POCO. So it should only contains the properties(getters and setters) you want to collect. You can then map this DTO/POCO to your business domain model.

```
  [HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Log(LogInfo logInfo)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: So i won't need the JSON conversion?

Comment: You should not have the conversion in the server side. The .NET web api framework should do that for you.